# Splitting multiline string into arrays in a function

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to split a multiline string into array in a function. I have got two implementations.

```sh
ToArray () {
  local arg1=$1
  local -n arg2=$2
  
  SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS
  IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to new line
  arg2=($arg1) # split to array $names
  IFS=$SAVEIFS   # Restore IFS
}

ToArray3 () {
  local arg1
  local list=()

  local SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS
  IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to new line
  while read arg1; do
    list+=("$arg1")
  done
  IFS=$SAVEIFS

  echo "${list[@]}" 
}

#These lines are just to simulate app's output. I have no control over these.
now=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m.%S+0000")
nl=$'\n'
foo="$now [APP/TASK/ValidateTask/0] OUT Test Run Successful.$nl$now[APP/TASK/ValidateTask/0] OUT Test Run UnSuccessful." 

ToArray "$foo" foobarbaz
# foobarbaz=( $(echo "$foo" | ToArray3) )
for (( i=0; i<${#foobarbaz[@]}; i++ ))
do
  value=${foobarbaz[$i]}
  echo "$i: $value"
done
```

`ToArray` works just fine, but I can't figure out why `ToArray3` is not working. I have already tried a bunch of things so there is a bunch of junk in there. Can anyone help me get `ToArray3` working?

Comment: There's a builtin for that, [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) (or its alias, `readarray`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has 2 errors.

The first one is in the function `ToArray3`:

- the script `echo` all the element of `list` in a single line not separated by `'\n'`

The second one in in the "main" function:

- the script use the auto-initilizer of the list **without set** the `IFS` to the `'\n'` special character. In this way all the space are used as separator.

The right script is the following:

```
  ToArray () {
      local arg1=$1
      local -n arg2=$2
      
      SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS
      IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to new line
      arg2=($arg1) # split to array $names
      IFS=$SAVEIFS   # Restore IFS
    }
    
    ToArray3 () {
      local arg1
      local list=()
    
      local SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS
      IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to new line
      while read arg1; do
        list+=("$arg1")
      done
      IFS=$SAVEIFS
      for (( i=0; i<${#list[@]}; i++ ))
      do
        echo ${list[$i]}
      done
    }
    
    #These lines are just to simulate app's output. I have no control over these.
    now=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m.%S+0000")
    nl=$'\n'
    
    foo="$now [APP/TASK/ValidateTask/0] OUT Test Run Successful.$nl$now[APP/TASK/ValidateTask/0] OUT Test Run UnSuccessful." 
    SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS
    IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to new line
    #ToArray "$foo" foobarbaz
     foobarbaz=( $(echo "$foo" | ToArray3) )
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
    for (( i=0; i<${#foobarbaz[@]}; i++ ))
    do
      value=${foobarbaz[$i]}
      echo "$i: $value"
    done
```